# Google Maps API V3 - Custom .GIF Markers not showing in IE when resized

Tags: internet-explorer, api, resize, maps

I have been trying to figure this out for some time and can't seem to get it to work or find a solution on the message board.

I am trying use a custom marker in a google map using API V3. It needs to be a .gif file rather than a .png as IE doesn't seem to support the alpha channel in the .png.
It also needs to be scaled down in size as it is quite a complex image with text that I am using and when you resize the image in photoshop/paint all the detail is lost and it becomes very pixelated. I have found that the only way around this seems to be through scaling it within the .html file.

My current html solution works in FF, Chrome, Safari & Opera, but not in IE (I don't even get a map just a blank white screen).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I don't seem to be getting anywhere when searching online. My HTML file is printed below....

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function initialize() {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.500656, -0.124594);


            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                zoom: 14,
                center: latLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });




            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                draggable: true,
                map: map,
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.activityvillage.co.uk/images/Big_Ben.gif", null, null, new google.maps.Point(66, 200), new google.maps.Size(136, 200)),
            });


            var label = new Label({
                map: map
            });


            label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');
            label.bindTo('text', marker, 'position');
        };

    </script>
</head>
    <body onload="initialize()">

        <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>

    </body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the last comma in the marker structure:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://www.activityvillage.co.uk/images/Big_Ben.gif", 
        null, 
        null, 
        new google.maps.Point(66, 200), 
        new google.maps.Size(136, 200)
    )
});​
```

My map wasn't showing at all because of a similar mistake. To quote Zepher Dev:

"There are many possible errors in Javascript that could account for the missing Google map. However, my issue was with trailing commas. IE7 (and sometime IE8) does not like trailing commas because it expects an identifier—hence the warning: “expected identifier.”

Hope this works for ya!